# Hide picklist based on condition

Tags: apex, rerender

I have 2 picklists countries & states, when I select a country it brings in the states. But my condition is if countries other than United States and Canada are selected then the state picklist should not be shown,if the countries selected are United States & Canada only then states picklist should be shown.
Here is the code I have but I am unable to achieve the above requirement.
**VF:**

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!fanCountry_Region}" size="1">                                                    
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesList}"></apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectList>

 <apex:selectList id="StatesList" value="{!fanState}" size="1">                
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!statesList}"></apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectList>
```

**Controller:**

```
public String fanCountry_Region { get; set; }
public String fanState { get; set; }
public List<selectOption> countriesList { 
        set; 
        get{

            List<selectOption> countriesList = new List<selectOption>();
            countriesList.add(new selectOption(' ','--Select--'));

            map<string,Countries__c> countryMap = Countries__c.getAll();
            List<string> countries = new List<string>();
            countries.addAll(countryMap.keySet());
            countries.sort();

            for(string country : countries){

                Countries__c c = countryMap.get(country);
                countriesList.add(new selectOption(c.CountryCode__c, c.Name));
            }

            return countriesList; 
        } 
    }

  public List<selectOption> statesList { 
        set; 
        get{

            List<selectOption> statesList = new List<selectOption>();

            Map<String, States__c> allstates = States__c.getAll();
            Map<string, States__c> states = new Map<string, States__c>();
            for(States__c state : allstates.values()) { 
                if (state.countryCode__c == fanCountry_Region) { 
                    states.put(state.name, state); 
                } 
            }

            List<String> stateNames = new List<String>(); 
            stateNames.addAll(states.keySet()); 
            stateNames.sort(); 

            for (String stateName : stateNames) { 
                States__c state = states.get(stateName); 
                statesList.add(new SelectOption(state.StateCode__c, state.Name)); 
            } 

            if (statesList.size() > 0) { 
                statesList.add(0, new SelectOption(' ', '-- Select One --')); 
            } else { 
                statesList.add(new SelectOption(' ', 'Not Required')); 
            }

            return statesList;  
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use Actionfunction to pass selected Country value to the Controller.
- Use `<apex:outputPanel/>` for rerendering the state list which is called from actionFunction.
- Use `rendered` condition in stateList based on Country selection.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="displayStatesList" action="{!displayStateList}" immediate="true" reRender="stateId">
     <apex:param id="fanCountry_Region" name="fanCountry_Region" value="{!fanCountry_Region}"/> 
</apex:actionFunction>

 <apex:selectList value="{!fanCountry_Region}" size="1" onchange="displayStatesList(this.value)">                                                    
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesList}">
    </apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectList>

 <apex:outputPanel id="stateId">
     <apex:selectList id="StatesList" value="{!fanState}" size="1" rendered="{!(fanCountry_Region ='United States' || fanCountry_Region='Canada')}">                
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!statesList}"></apex:selectOptions>
     </apex:selectList>
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Controller**

```
public void displayStateList()
 {
    //put a code to load states based on region

 }
```

Comment: in my prev code, statesList is a property, as per new change statesList is a method. doe this make a difference?The VF page is same as above.The state is still visible if country=Canada. if country="Be;gium" then state should show 'Not required' but thats not happening

Comment: you can change the code, I have given an approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below to logic to control when state pick list needs to be rendered

> rendered="{!if(fanCountry_Region=='United States' ||
>   fanCountry_Region=='Canada')}"

and then rerender state picklist whenever country picklist value changes using actionSupport

**VF code:**

```
<apex:selectList value="{!fanCountry_Region}" size="1">                                                    
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!countriesList}"></apex:selectOptions>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="StatesList"/>
 </apex:selectList>

 <apex:selectList id="StatesList" value="{!fanState}" size="1" rendered="{!if(fanCountry_Region=='United States' || fanCountry_Region=='Canada',true,false)}">                
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!statesList}"></apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: `rendered` condition either returns true or false, so do not need `if` condition

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. Will edit the answer.